# The meaning of "Stand to it!"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

"Stand to it," in my understanding, is a slightly archaic expression. What does it mean?

I have seen it in a book title and a sentence written in the 18th century.

> "**Stand to It** and Give Them Hell": Gettysburg as the Soldiers Experienced it from Cemetery Ridge to Little Round Top, July 2, 1863 (A [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MJK2YKI) title)
>
> Therefore my friends, **stand to it** one and all, refuse this filthy trash. (1724, Jonathan Swift, The Drapier's Letters, Letter I)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two definitions listed in the OED for "stand to it" (both are listed under *stand, v.*):

> To apply oneself manfully to (a fight, contest, etc.). *Obs*. exc. in to **stand to it**, to fight stoutly; also, to toil without flagging at painful or severe labour.

> **to stand to it**: to insist upon or maintain a statement or assertion; often with *that* and clause (sometimes without *that*).

(Both of these expressions were still in use during the time periods you mention.)